# How to query for multiple types of an object (using a key-value table) and grouping the results together as a complete object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I hope I asked the question properly. I have a table of objects grouped by object_id. They are stored as a key / value. I thought this would be simple but I cannot find a solution anywhere. I'm trying to get the most efficient method of querying against this table to return a full object based on multiple meta_name values. Here's the table structure:

[image: Database Structure]

Here's the code I have so far, which works great to query one value:

```
SELECT data2.object_id,data2.object, data2.meta_name, data2.value_string, data2.value_text FROM meta_data AS data1
LEFT JOIN meta_data AS data2 ON(data1.object_id = data2.object_id)
data1.object="domain"
AND data1.meta_name = "category"
AND data1.value_string = "programmer"
```

This gives me the following results. This is great for a single taxonomy (domain in category programmer).

[image: Results]

The problem comes when I want to query for all domains with category programmer AND color red AND possibly other meta_name = value_strings. I can find no solution for this outside of making multiple queries from PHP (which I want to avoid for obvious performance reasons).

I need to point out that objects will be created on the fly, and without a specific schema (which is the point of having this structure to begin with) so I cannot hard code and assume anything about an object (Objects may have more meta properties defined to them from the admin panel at any given time).

Again, I hope I am asking this question right, since I have been completely unlucky in finding a solution by searching online for the last 3 days.

Thank you so much ahead of time to the MySQL pro that can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this solutions typically query all records to avoid multiple queries and then *stitch* data objects together to provide the desired format. Then you can develop simple `find()` methods on those objects to further filter the results (e.g. using array functions)

If you're interested in exact implementation, I encourage you to look at WordPress - you noted taxonomies. As an open source project you can [review their code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/) for an example of how this is done. Take a look at the [Taxonomies API](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php) as well as [Meta API](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/meta.php).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually this entire concept stemmed from a limitation that we've been trying to get around in WP. In our situation every object can be a taxonomy, whereas Wordpress you define a taxonomy outside of the content type. Notice in my database you have a "category" object, which can also have it's own metadata (such as nouns, verbs,  etc) and can also be queried based on it's name ('android' for example). As far as we could come up with, it was not practical to do this in WP, which is what we really wanted to do in the first place actually.

Comment: To further complicate things, the domain has multiple categories (which are objects themselves with their own metadata). So the domain spinpress.lc would contain not only it's meta data, but the category(ies) meta data as well. My only concern is, will the find() methods be able to handles many thousands of records returned efficiently? If that's the case, then this is definitely a good solution. Otherwise I would hope to find a pure SQL solution to the problem (if one exists)